# Preventing Duplicates when using Parallel Processing on a ToDo List

Tags: multithreading, azure, parallel-processing, azure-sql-database, azure-worker-roles

I have, for example, a todo list, represented as a rows in a database with a 'IsComplete' field.

At the end of each hour, I want to find all the todos not marked as complete, and send a reminder to their individual creators.

There are millions of todos created each hour, and sending a reminder is an expensive process.

I have single a worker role which will happily run each hour to get these incomplete todos, and add each one to a service bus queue to be picked up by a separate group of worker roles which deal with the expensive task of sending the reminders.

The problems faced in this scenario are:

1. If the single worker might fail, resulting in no todos being
   added to the queue for processing.
2. Running multiple instances of the worker role, will result in duplicates as each instance competes with each other to add the todos to the que.
3. Even if the queue rejects those duplicates, the database is subject to being queried for the same data multiple times by each instance, even if those todos have been processed and added to the reminders que.
4. Even if the worker role scanned the database to see if the todos have had reminders created, again, if they happen to check at the same time, it's possible for more than one  role to believe the todo needs a reminder.
5. Scanning the database for todos is also expensive because there are so many, the worker roles can't divide this work load between them.

What patterns are there that can solve or avoid this sort of concurrency issue?  Is having multiple roles scan the same tables the draw back for the protection offered by running multiple roles in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly look at `Master/Slave` pattern.

Assuming you have `x` number of worker roles. At the start of every hour one worker role from `x` worker role would become a master. This can be accomplished by acquiring a lease on a blob. All instances will try to acquire a lease on same blob and only one will succeed. The one which succeeds will be designated as `Master`.

Now the `Master` could fetch the data from database and push the messages in a queue. All `Slave` instances will poll this queue and as messages start arriving in the queue, slave instances will `GET` one or more messages and process them. If an instance fails to process the message, it will reappear in the queue after some time (visibility timeout) so that other instance can now get this message and process it.